# Finding row/column names from a correlation matrix values

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a correlation matrix, that contains stock price correlations.
it was calculated via:

```
corMatrix <- cor(cl2014, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

The matrix is much bigger but looks like this:

```
> corMatrix
             RY.TO.Close CM.TO.Close BNS.TO.Close TD.TO.Close
RY.TO.Close    1.0000000   0.8990782    0.8700985  -0.2505789
CM.TO.Close    0.8990782   1.0000000    0.8240780  -0.4184085
BNS.TO.Close   0.8700985   0.8240780    1.0000000  -0.2141785
TD.TO.Close   -0.2505789  -0.4184085   -0.2141785   1.0000000

> class(corMatrix)
[1] "matrix"
```

I'm trying to determine how I can get the row and column names of all values in the matrix that have a correlation greater than some value.

I can index the matrix to generate an index matrix like so:

```
workingset <- corMatrix > 0.85
```

What I really want is just a list of row/col pairs identified by the row and column name so I know what pairs to do further exploration on.

How can I go from the indexing grid to the row/column names?

I'd ideally also only examine only the lower or upper portion of the matrix as to not generate duplicate values and of course the main diagonal can be ignored as it will always be 1.

Comment: Maybe `which(corMatrix > 0.85, arr.ind = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another option is to use `melt` from "reshape2" and `subset`:

```
library(reshape2)
subset(melt(corMatrix), value > .85)
#            Var1         Var2     value
# 1   RY.TO.Close  RY.TO.Close 1.0000000
# 2   CM.TO.Close  RY.TO.Close 0.8990782
# 3  BNS.TO.Close  RY.TO.Close 0.8700985
# 5   RY.TO.Close  CM.TO.Close 0.8990782
# 6   CM.TO.Close  CM.TO.Close 1.0000000
# 9   RY.TO.Close BNS.TO.Close 0.8700985
# 11 BNS.TO.Close BNS.TO.Close 1.0000000
# 16  TD.TO.Close  TD.TO.Close 1.0000000
```

---

You would need to do `melt(as.matrix(corMatrix))` if your dataset is a `data.frame` since there are different `melt` methods for matrices and `data.frame`s.

---

### Update

As you mention you're only interested in the values from the upper triangle (to avoid duplicate pairs/values) and excluding the diagonal, you can do the following:

```
CM <- corMatrix                               # Make a copy of your matrix
CM[lower.tri(CM, diag = TRUE)] <- NA          # lower tri and diag set to NA
subset(melt(CM, na.rm = TRUE), value > .85)   # melt and subset as before
#          Var1         Var2     value
# 5 RY.TO.Close  CM.TO.Close 0.8990782
# 9 RY.TO.Close BNS.TO.Close 0.8700985
```

---

You could also do this with base R. Continuing with `"CM"` from above, try:

```
subset(na.omit(data.frame(expand.grid(dimnames(CM)), value = c(CM))), value > .85)
#          Var1         Var2     value
# 5 RY.TO.Close  CM.TO.Close 0.8990782
# 9 RY.TO.Close BNS.TO.Close 0.8700985
```

Comment: great answer, thank you!  I didn't know about lower.tri.  The more I dig into R the more I realize its more about the libraries than syntax

Comment: @chollida, `lower.tri` is part of base R, not a package!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `which` to get a matrix of row/col pairs.  Use the `arr.ind` argument. Then we can match the row and column names for the pairs and put them into a data frame with their respective values.

```
w <- which(corMatrix > 0.85, arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(row = rownames(w), col = colnames(corMatrix)[w[, "col"]], 
           value = corMatrix[corMatrix > 0.85])
#            row          col     value
# 1  RY.TO.Close  RY.TO.Close 1.0000000
# 2  CM.TO.Close  RY.TO.Close 0.8990782
# 3 BNS.TO.Close  RY.TO.Close 0.8700985
# 4  RY.TO.Close  CM.TO.Close 0.8990782
# 5  CM.TO.Close  CM.TO.Close 1.0000000
# 6  RY.TO.Close BNS.TO.Close 0.8700985
# 7 BNS.TO.Close BNS.TO.Close 1.0000000
# 8  TD.TO.Close  TD.TO.Close 1.0000000
```

Comment: that's great, it's closer than I was before, but it doesn't give me the row and column name for matches.  Is there a way to retrieve both?

Comment: +1, but don't you get `rownames` in "w", allowing you to just do `cbind(rownames(w), colnames(corMatrix)[w[, "col"]])`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto - yep, thanks. Much cleaner that way.  Made an edit

Answer (score 1):

Adding to accepted answer,

```
subset(melt(corMatrix)), value > .75 & value < 1.0)
subset(melt(corMatrix)), value < -.75 & value > -1.0)
```

would be more accurate I suppose. 'Correlation can be negative too'